# XAMPP on WIndows 8. New PHP files are blank

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I have installed XAMPP onto my Windows machine and all seems ok as I can open the home page, view the phpinfo() link etc.

However, any new PHP file I create and open my browser to is just presenting a blank page! I have created a folder within htdocs and uploaded my file to there. The file simply contains 
    
but nothing is returned!

If I adjust the phpinfo.php file that is created with then XAMPP installation with the above code, it works fine!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Add more details (share code or screen). Make sure your file extension is correct.

Comment: "The file simply contains but nothing is returned!" what is that supposed to say? Post the contents here and the error log file excerpts. But most likely your php files simply do not produce any output.

Comment: hmm seems the code I added was removed. The file extension is correct - .php. The code within the file is [code] <?php $name = "Mike"; echo $name; ?> but even if I do [code] <?php phpinfo(); ?> nothing is returned... yet the phpinfo.php file created by the XAMPP installation works!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the display error directive is disabled. Try enabling it on .htaccess or on php.ini.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score -2):

check properly. you might not have specified your path correctly to include the folder name, try something like   "http://localhost:1234/your  folder name/ index.php" it works perfectly for me